# get data from multiple text boxes Code Igniter

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter, for-loop

i am newbie in a code igniter .. so first i'll let you know what i am trying to do . i have two select boxes and three simple text boxes in a row ..so now it means i have five input boxes in one row  .. the value of second dropdown comes based on the first drop down boxe.means if i select some thing from first select box then the values against the first selection will come in a second dropdown or select box..and by the way  values are coming dynmically from the database . ok after then i have make five rows with for loop .. and now only the select boxes of first row is working .. not other four rows .. and i want to grab all the values which filled by the user
here is my view

```
         <tr>
<th>Category:</th>
<th>Items:</th>
<th>Selling Price:</th>
<th>quantity:</th>
<th> total:</th>
</tr>

    <?php for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
        ?>
        <tr>
               <td>     


<?php echo form_dropdown('cat_id', $records2, '#', 'id="category"');?>
        </td>
       <td>                 

<?php echo form_dropdown('item_id', $records3, '#', 'id="items"'); ?>

    </td>           

  <td><?php echo form_input($price); ?> </td>

           <td><?php echo form_input($quantity); ?></td>

           <td> <?php echo form_input($total); ?>
            </td></tr>

   <?php }?></table>
```

my javascript

```
   $(document).ready(function(){  
     $('#check').click(function(){
         alert("hello");
         return false;
     });
    $('#category').change(function(){ 
        $("#items > option").remove();
        var category_id = $('#category').val();  
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "stockInController/get_Items/"+category_id, 

            success: function(items) //we're calling the response json array 'cities'
            {
                $.each(items,function(item_id,item_name) 
                {
                    var opt = $('<option />'); 
                    opt.val(item_id);
                    opt.text(item_name);
                    $('#items').append(opt);
                });
            }

        });

    });
});
```

i thing i have to given each select box an id with $i but i dont know how can then i do this in jquery ...remember only my first row is successfully working not other four

Comment: You have to use arrays in select boxes and then process these arrays in javascript.
<?php echo form_dropdown('cat_id[]', $records2, '#', 'id="category[]"');?>
<?php echo form_dropdown('item_id[]', $records3, '#', 'id="items[]"'); ?>

Comment: thanks to you .. but i dont know how to i do this is javascript ..can you do this ?..

Comment: so now if your `select boxes` had same ids then only the first one will be worked. I suggest you to change `id` to `class`.

Comment: I agree with jai in that.

Comment: @jai .. nope it didnt work .. after changing to class if i select one option from first dropdown of first  row ..it'll change all the option of not only the first select box of first row but all the select boxes

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this jquery plugin - it will make your life much easier

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained

Comment: yeah thanks to you .. but the problem is that i dont know about how to use json

Comment: @user1972143 - then start with simple tutorials like [this](http://www.packtpub.com/article/working-json-php-jquery)